# Facebook app canvas page: page not found

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Im trying to create a facebook app with a canvas page. When i try to visit the page using its url it works as intented: http://dyndns.patrikelfstrom.se/johan/fb/fysiosteo

But when i try to visit it using facebook: https://apps.facebook.com/387677594596809

"This webpage is not available"

Is this because the server that im hosting the page on doesnt support SSL? Or did i miss something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

Going to: http://apps.facebook.com/387677594596809/
works perfectly.

Comment: Does it? I get redirected to the https

Comment: Try entering the page when not logged in to Facebook. You are probably using Facebook's secure browsing feature which redirects all content to https.

Comment: Ok, but i guess there is no workaround regarding the https hosting? Since the users who visits the page will be logged in, hence get redirected...

Comment: There is no workaround. Facebook requires now to have a secure version for every app.